# Webgl Rotation Effect

Tags: matrix, rotation, webgl, cube

I try to make a Rubics Cube. If I rotate the cube fast I have got a strange effect. Can you say me what is wrong? Look hier: http://tyrannxx.lima-city.de/cube.png

Comment: To maximize your chance of being helped on SO always try to include a code sample which illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to clear your depth and/or color buffer.

This line is to execute before each frame :

```
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: That was the solution to my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please validate my answer by clicking on the green symbol to make clear that that was the solution.